# AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Npm errors can't download packages

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to host a react web client on Elastic Beanstalk and there is an error when the app tries to download the packages, I can't figure out how to resolve it

here are the logs of eb-engine.log :

https://pastebin.com/4MiaMAgP

I don't understand what's wrong [image]

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=6.0.0",
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  },
  "name": "vaulth-web-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "ethers": "^5.5.2",
    "firebase": "^9.6.1",
    "material-icons-react": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^4.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "state-pool": "^0.6.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: May be this...npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i'll check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why, but it seems that the host was not powerful enough, I've changed the instance from `t2.micro` to `t2.small`, and it worked

I think the server was indeed not big enough for what I wanted to use it for, but the errors needs to be a bit more precise